# Getting "Can not convert the given object to query." with ColdFusion ORM

Tags: orm, coldfusion, mura, fw1

This is happening intermittently (usually at start up).  I get the above error message when executing the following code.

```
    var arr     = ORMExecuteQuery( "FROM priority WHERE active = 1 ORDER BY sortOrder" );
    var qry     = entityToQuery( arr );
```

The first line executes fine, but the second line blows up.  The solution is to run `ormreload();`

The problem keeps coming up in an unpredictable way though.  Even when no changes have been made to the beans or gateways that are using ORM.  Completely unpredictable and impossible to replicate on purpose.  Is there something else that can mess with the hibernate mappings that could cause this type of problem.

Other info that may be pertinent:

- This is a MURA plugin based on a recent version of FW/1.
- `ormreload()` is a persistent fix (until it fails again)

My current solution is to put `ormreload()` in the `setupApplication()` method of application.cfc

I just want to understand better what could be causing this problem.

Comment: Dumb question here...but do you really need to covert the array to a query? I use ORM extensively in my applications and I have never had a need to use `entityToQuery()`. If you really need a query object, why bother with ORM? Just run a SQL query instead.

Comment: @ScottStroz Great question.  I have rarely used CF ORM in the past.  I had my own lightweight ORM that worked really well for me. Now, I'm working with an inherited app and I'm trying keep tools consistent throughout the existing project.  In this case, I'm trying get a list of all priorities so that I can populate a pick list.  The picklist is a built using some customized UI tag libraries (also inherited). So the picklist is looking for a query object. So I could refactor, but still trying to figure out why entityToQuery is flaky for me. Thanks for the suggestion though.  I may go that way.

Comment: Make sure that `var arr` is not an empty array. `entityToQuery` only works if there are rows in the array.

Comment: Using ORM and then converting to a query could be a lot of overhead. Which is why I tend to stick to one or the other.

Comment: @JamesAMohler Array is not empty.  Note that ORMreload fixes the problem.  And it isn't a cache issue...dump and abort shows values.  Removing the abort throws the error.  Then ormReload fixes the problem.

Comment: @ScottStroz  Trying to buy into the CF ORM way, but I really really like SQL.  Might abandon the ORM and go native!

Comment: None of this really addresses the issue.  Has no one experienced intermittent issues related to entityToQuery? I'm not really in need of a solution or work around.  I have that.  I'm confused about the underlying workings of the tool.  I have an inherent distrust of things that work "automagically".  I don't mind using libraries and custom tags or frameworks or even coding by convention.  But I do want to understand why things work and why they don't.  This doesn't make sense to me and I was hoping someone had some experience with it.  Looking for the wisdom of the crowd!

Comment: With all problems, you should try to reproduce the error. You mention that `ORMReload` fixes the problem. To me that means that you should do a `<cfdump>` both before and after and see what changed